# Kobo by FNAC does not show covers when sleeping

Tags: kobo, cover

I've got a new Kobo and, although I've heard it used to show book covers when sleeping, mine only shows the FNAC logo in the screen. First I thought it used to happen because I was only using it to read Pocket articles, but then I started a book and it's behaving the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out it's a factory setting for the FNAC versions. It can be changed by connecting it to your computer and editing a file inside a hidden folder: `.kobo/affiliate.conf`.
You should change it from `affiliate=fnac` to `affiliate=Kobo`.

This was found at a [MobileRead Forum post](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=164697), and I thought it should be here for making it easier to be found.